# JSSOR Slider add thumbnail navigator and Captions to different-size-photo slider

Tags: slider, caption, jssor, navigator

Okay, so far I have managed to mutilate...uh, I mean "manipulate" ;-) 
the JSSOR Different-size-photo-slider to add a Thumbnail Navigator *below* the slides,
and it's actually working, even with a different transition for each image. 
But now I'm stuck at trying to also add a caption to each slide. 
I *can* add the captions to the different-sized images WITHOUT the thumbnails at the bottom, but can't figure out how to combine the code to have BOTH (a caption on each slide AND the navigation thumbnails below the slides). 
Any suggestions, how I might be able to accomplish this? (I only need the *name* for each image, added at the bottom edge of each slide)

Here is my current code for the Different-size-photo-slider with the Thumbnail Navigator
(Just don't laugh too hard..I realize it's probably a mess, but I'm just glad I got *this far* with it)

```
<BODY link="#99CCFF" vlink="#99CCFF" alink="#99CCFF" style="color: #FFFFFF;" bgcolor="#202020">
<SCRIPT src="JS/f.txt" async=""></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT src="JS/jssor.js" type="text/javascript"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT src="JS/jssor.slider.js" type="text/javascript"></SCRIPT>
<div class="container" align="center"
>
<SCRIPT>
var _SlideshowTransitions = [
                //Wave out Eagle
                {$Duration:1500,y:-0.5,$Delay:60,$Cols:15,$SlideOut:true,$Formation:$JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationCircle,$Easing:$JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave,$Round:{$Top:1.5}},
                //Rotate Overlap
                { $Duration: 1200, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: -1, $Easing: { $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.5 }, $Brother: { $Duration: 1200, $Zoom: 1, $Rotate: 1, $Easing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseSwing, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.5 }, $Shift: 90 } },
                //Switch
                { $Duration: 1400, x: 0.25, $Zoom: 1.5, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInSine }, $Opacity: 2, $ZIndex: -10, $Brother: { $Duration: 1400, x: -0.25, $Zoom: 1.5, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInSine }, $Opacity: 2, $ZIndex: -10 } },
                //Rotate Relay
                { $Duration: 1200, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $Easing: { $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 1 }, $ZIndex: -10, $Brother: { $Duration: 1200, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: -1, $Easing: { $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 1 }, $ZIndex: -10, $Shift: 600 } },
                //Fade Stairs
                {$Duration:1600,x:-0.2,$Delay:40,$Cols:12,$During:{$Left:[0.4,0.6]},$SlideOut:true,$Formation:$JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraight,$Assembly:260,$Easing:{$Left:$JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutExpo,$Opacity:$JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutQuad},$Opacity:2,$Outside:true,$Round:{$Top:0.5},$Brother:{$Duration:1000,x:0.2,$Delay:40,$Cols:12,$Formation:$JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraight,$Assembly:1028,$Easing:{$Left:$JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutExpo,$Opacity:$JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutQuad},$Opacity:2,$Round:{$Top:0.5}}},
                //Flutter Inside Out Swirl
                {$Duration:1800,x:1,y:0.2,$Delay:30,$Cols:10,$Rows:5,$Clip:15,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7],$Top:[0.3,0.7]},$SlideOut:true,$Reverse:true,$Formation:$JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationSwirl,$Assembly:2050,$Easing:{$Left:$JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine,$Top:$JssorEasing$.$EaseOutWave,$Clip:$JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutQuad},$Round:{$Top:1.3}},
                //Fly Twins
                { $Duration: 1500, x: 0.3, $During: { $Left: [0.6, 0.4] }, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Opacity: 2, $Outside: true, $Brother: { $Duration: 1000, x: -0.3, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Opacity: 2 } },
                //Rotate in- out+
                { $Duration: 1500, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 0.5, $During: { $Left: [0.4, 0.6], $Top: [0.4, 0.6], $Rotate: [0.4, 0.6], $Zoom: [0.4, 0.6] }, $Easing: { $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad }, $Opacity: 2, $Brother: { $Duration: 1000, $Zoom: 1, $Rotate: -0.5, $Easing: { $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad }, $Opacity: 2, $Shift: 200 } },
                //Rotate Axis up overlap
                { $Duration: 1200, x: 0.25, y: 0.5, $Rotate: -0.1, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad }, $Opacity: 2, $Brother: { $Duration: 1200, x: -0.1, y: -0.7, $Rotate: 0.1, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad }, $Opacity: 2 } },
                //Chess Replace TB
                { $Duration: 1600, x: 1, $Rows: 2, $ChessMode: { $Row: 3 }, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutQuart, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Opacity: 2, $Brother: { $Duration: 1600, x: -1, $Rows: 2, $ChessMode: { $Row: 3 }, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutQuart, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Opacity: 2 } },
                //Extrude Replace
                {$Duration:1600,x:-0.2,$Delay:40,$Cols:12,$During:{$Left:[0.4,0.6]},$SlideOut:true,$Formation:$JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraight,$Assembly:260,$Easing:{$Left:$JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutExpo,$Opacity:$JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutQuad},$Opacity:2,$Outside:true,$Round:{$Top:0.5},$Brother:{$Duration:1000,x:0.2,$Delay:40,$Cols:12,$Formation:$JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraight,$Assembly:1028,$Easing:{$Left:$JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutExpo,$Opacity:$JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutQuad},$Opacity:2,$Round:{$Top:0.5}}},
                //Shift TB
                { $Duration: 1200, y: 1, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutQuart, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Opacity: 2, $Brother: { $Duration: 1200, y: -1, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutQuart, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Opacity: 2 } },
                //Shift LR
                { $Duration: 1200, x: 1, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutQuart, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Opacity: 2, $Brother: { $Duration: 1200, x: -1, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutQuart, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Opacity: 2 } },
                //Return TB
                { $Duration: 1200, y: -1, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutQuart, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Opacity: 2, $ZIndex: -10, $Brother: { $Duration: 1200, y: -1, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutQuart, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Opacity: 2, $ZIndex: -10, $Shift: -100 } },
                //Return LR
                { $Duration: 1200, x: 1, $Delay: 40, $Cols: 6, $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraight, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutQuart, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Opacity: 2, $ZIndex: -10, $Brother: { $Duration: 1200, x: 1, $Delay: 40, $Cols: 6, $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraight, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutQuart, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Opacity: 2, $ZIndex: -10, $Shift: -100 } },
                //Rotate Axis down
                { $Duration: 1500, x: -0.1, y: -0.7, $Rotate: 0.1, $During: { $Left: [0.6, 0.4], $Top: [0.6, 0.4], $Rotate: [0.6, 0.4] }, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad }, $Opacity: 2, $Brother: { $Duration: 1000, x: 0.2, y: 0.5, $Rotate: -0.1, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad }, $Opacity: 2 } },
                //Extrude Replace
                {$Duration:1600,x:-0.2,$Delay:40,$Cols:12,$During:{$Left:[0.4,0.6]},$SlideOut:true,$Formation:$JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraight,$Assembly:260,$Easing:{$Left:$JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutExpo,$Opacity:$JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutQuad},$Opacity:2,$Outside:true,$Round:{$Top:0.5},$Brother:{$Duration:1000,x:0.2,$Delay:40,$Cols:12,$Formation:$JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraight,$Assembly:1028,$Easing:{$Left:$JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutExpo,$Opacity:$JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutQuad},$Opacity:2,$Round:{$Top:0.5}}}
            ];

        jssor_slider1_starter = function (containerId) {
            var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(containerId, {
                $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
                $AutoPlayInterval: 1500,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
                $PauseOnHover: 1,                                //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, 4 freeze for desktop, 8 freeze for touch device, 12 freeze for desktop and touch device, default value is 1

                $DragOrientation: 1,                                 //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $Cols is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)
                $FillMode: 1,                                        //[Optional] The way to fill image in slide, 0 stretch, 1 contain (keep aspect ratio and put all inside slide), 2 cover (keep aspect ratio and cover whole slide), 4 actuall size, default value is 0
                $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                          //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
                $SlideDuration: 800,                                //Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds

                $SlideshowOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable slideshow or not
                    $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,                 //[Required] Class to create instance of slideshow
                    $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,            //[Required] An array of slideshow transitions to play slideshow
                    $TransitionsOrder: 1,                           //[Optional] The way to choose transition to play slide, 1 Sequence, 0 Random
                    $ShowLink: false                                    //[Optional] Whether to bring slide link on top of the slider when slideshow is running, default value is false
                },

                $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {                       //[Optional] Options to specify and enable arrow navigator or not
                    $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                    $ChanceToShow: 1                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                },

                $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {                       //[Optional] Options to specify and enable thumbnail navigator or not
                    $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,              //[Required] Class to create thumbnail navigator instance
                    $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always

                    $SpacingX: 8,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each thumbnail in pixel, default value is 0
                    $Cols: 10,                             //[Optional] Number of pieces to display, default value is 1
                    $Align: 360                          //[Optional] The offset position to park thumbnail
                }
            });
            //responsive code begin
            //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
            function ScaleSlider() {
                var windowWidth = $Jssor$.$WindowSize().x;
                if (windowWidth)
                    jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.max(Math.min(windowWidth, 800), 300));
                else
                    $Jssor$.$Delay(ScaleSlider, 30);
            }

            ScaleSlider();
            $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "load", ScaleSlider);


            if (!navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|BlackBerry|IEMobile)/)) {
                $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "resize", $Jssor$.$WindowResizeFilter(window, ScaleSlider));
            }

            //if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad)/)) {
            //    $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
            //}
            //responsive code end
        };
</SCRIPT>

 </DIV>
<DIV style="height: 20px;"></DIV>
<DIV id="slider1_container" style="background-image: url('Dark2.jpg'); margin: 0px auto; width: 800px; height: 750px; position: relative;">
<DIV style="left: 0px; top: 0px; position: absolute;" u="loading">
<DIV style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block; position: absolute; opacity: 0.7; background-image: url('Dark2.jpg'));"></DIV>
<DIV style='background: url("loading.gif") no-repeat center; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block; position: absolute;'></DIV></DIV>
<DIV style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 800px; height: 650px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; cursor: move" 
u="slides">
<DIV>
    <IMG src="Beemer1.jpg" 
u="image">
    <IMG src="BeemerTN.jpg" 
u="thumb"></DIV>
<!. Beemer.! >
<DIV>
    <IMG src="Ben1.jpg" 
u="image"> 
    <IMG src="BenTN.jpg" 
u="thumb"></DIV>
<DIV>
    <IMG src="Bernard1.jpg"
u="image"> 
    <IMG src="BernardTN.jpg" 
u="thumb"></DIV>
<DIV>
    <IMG src="Betsy1.jpg"
u="image"> 
    <IMG src="BetsyTN.jpg" 
u="thumb"></DIV>
<DIV>
    <IMG src="Buttons1.jpg"
u="image"> 
    <IMG src="ButtonsTN.jpg" 
u="thumb"></DIV>
<DIV>
    <IMG src="Cooper1.jpg"
u="image"> 
    <IMG src="CooperTN.jpg" 
u="thumb"></DIV>
<DIV>
    <IMG src="Daisey1.jpg"
u="image"> 
    <IMG src="DaiseyTN.jpg" 
u="thumb"></DIV>
<DIV>
    <IMG src="Gus1.jpg"
u="image"> 
    <IMG src="GusTN.jpg" 
u="thumb"></DIV>
<DIV>
    <IMG src="Mako1.jpg"
u="image"> 
    <IMG src="MakoTN.jpg" 
u="thumb"></DIV>
<DIV>
    <IMG src="Malley1.jpg"
u="image"> 
    <IMG src="MalleyTN.jpg" 
u="thumb"></DIV>
<DIV>
    <IMG src="Maya1.jpg"
u="image"> 
    <IMG src="MayaTN.jpg" 
u="thumb"></DIV>
<DIV>
    <IMG src="Neko1.jpg"
u="image"> 
    <IMG src="NekoTN.jpg" 
u="thumb"></DIV>
<DIV>
    <IMG src="Sadie1.jpg"
u="image"> 
    <IMG src="SadieTN.jpg" 
u="thumb"></DIV>
<DIV>
    <IMG src="Sasha1.jpg"
u="image"> 
    <IMG src="SashaTN.jpg" 
u="thumb"></DIV>
<DIV>
    <IMG src="Sassy1.jpg"
u="image"> 
    <IMG src="SassyTN.jpg" 
u="thumb"></DIV>
<DIV>
    <IMG src="Spartacus1.jpg"
u="image"> 
    <IMG src="SpartacusTN.jpg" 
u="thumb"></DIV>
<DIV>
    <IMG src="Sumo1.jpg"
u="image"> 
    <IMG src="SumoTN.jpg" 
u="thumb"></DIV>
<DIV>
    <IMG src="Teddy1.jpg"
u="image"> 
    <IMG src="TeddyTN.jpg" 
u="thumb"></DIV>
<DIV>
    <IMG src="Vino1.jpg"
u="image"> 
    <IMG src="VinoTN.jpg" 
u="thumb"></DIV>
<DIV>
    <IMG src="Yogi1.jpg"
u="image"> 
    <IMG src="YogiTN.jpg" 
u="thumb"></DIV>
</DIV>
 <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin Begin -->
        <style>
            /* jssor slider arrow navigator skin 05 css */
            /*
            .jssora05l              (normal)
            .jssora05r              (normal)
            .jssora05l:hover        (normal mouseover)
            .jssora05r:hover        (normal mouseover)
            .jssora05ldn            (mousedown)
            .jssora05rdn            (mousedown)
            */
            .jssora05l, .jssora05r, .jssora05ldn, .jssora05rdn
            {
                position: absolute;
                cursor: pointer;
                display: block;
                background: url(a17.png) no-repeat;
                overflow:hidden;
            }
            .jssora05l { background-position: -10px -40px; }
            .jssora05r { background-position: -70px -40px; }
            .jssora05l:hover { background-position: -130px -40px; }
            .jssora05r:hover { background-position: -190px -40px; }
            .jssora05ldn { background-position: -250px -40px; }
            .jssora05rdn { background-position: -310px -40px; }
        </style>
        <!-- Arrow Left -->
        <span u="arrowleft" class="jssora05l" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; top: 158px; left: 8px;">
        </span>
        <!-- Arrow Right -->
        <span u="arrowright" class="jssora05r" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; top: 158px; right: 8px">
        </span>
        <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin End -->

        <!-- Thumbnail Navigator Skin Begin -->
        <div u="thumbnavigator" class="jssort01" style="position: absolute; width: 800px; height: 100px; background-image: url('Dark2.jpg'); left:0px; bottom: 0px;">
            <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin Begin -->
            <style>
                /* jssor slider thumbnail navigator skin 01 css */
                /*
                .jssort01 .p           (normal)
                .jssort01 .p:hover     (normal mouseover)
                .jssort01 .pav           (active)
                .jssort01 .pav:hover     (active mouseover)
                .jssort01 .pdn           (mousedown)
                */
                .jssort01 .w {
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 0px;
                    left: 0px;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                }

                .jssort01 .c {
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 0px;
                    left: 0px;
                    width: 68px;
                    height: 68px;
                    border: #404040 2px solid;
                }

                .jssort01 .p:hover .c, .jssort01 .pav:hover .c, .jssort01 .pav .c {
                    border: #FFF 2px solid;
                    top: 0px;
                    left: 0px;
                    width: 68px;
                    height: 68px;
                }

                .jssort01 .p:hover .c, .jssort01 .pav:hover .c {
                    top: 0px;
                    left: 0px;
                    width: 70px;
                    height: 70px;
                    border: #fff 1px solid;
                }
            </style>
            <div u="slides" style="cursor: move;">
                <div u="prototype" class="p" style="position: absolute; width: 72px; height: 72px; top: 0; left: 0;">
                    <div class=w><thumbnailtemplate style=" width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none;position:absolute; top: 0; left: 0;"></thumbnailtemplate></div>
                    <div class=c>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin End -->
        </div>
        <!-- Thumbnail Navigator Skin End --></DIV></DIV></DIV></DIV>
<SCRIPT>
jssor_slider1_starter('slider1_container');
</SCRIPT>
 </DIV>
 </DIV>
</DIV></DIV></DIV>
</div>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

***Define caption transitions, and add $CaptionSliderOptions***

```
        ...
        var _CaptionTransitions = [];
        _CaptionTransitions["L"] = { $Duration: 800, x: 0.6, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };

        ...

    jssor_slider1_starter = function (containerId) {
        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(containerId, {
            $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
            $AutoPlayInterval: 1500,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
            $PauseOnHover: 1,                                //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, 4 freeze for desktop, 8 freeze for touch device, 12 freeze for desktop and touch device, default value is 1

            $DragOrientation: 1,                                 //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $Cols is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)
            $FillMode: 1,                                        //[Optional] The way to fill image in slide, 0 stretch, 1 contain (keep aspect ratio and put all inside slide), 2 cover (keep aspect ratio and cover whole slide), 4 actuall size, default value is 0
            $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                          //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
            $SlideDuration: 800,                                //Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds

            $SlideshowOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable slideshow or not
                $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,                 //[Required] Class to create instance of slideshow
                $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,            //[Required] An array of slideshow transitions to play slideshow
                $TransitionsOrder: 1,                           //[Optional] The way to choose transition to play slide, 1 Sequence, 0 Random
                $ShowLink: false                                    //[Optional] Whether to bring slide link on top of the slider when slideshow is running, default value is false
            },

            $CaptionSliderOptions: {                            //[Optional] Options which specifies how to animate caption
                $Class: $JssorCaptionSlider$,                   //[Required] Class to create instance to animate caption
                $CaptionTransitions: _CaptionTransitions,       //[Required] An array of caption transitions to play caption, see caption transition section at jssor slideshow transition builder
                $PlayInMode: 1,                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes after main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes after main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
                $PlayOutMode: 3                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes before main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes before main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
            },

            $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {                       //[Optional] Options to specify and enable arrow navigator or not
                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                $ChanceToShow: 1                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
            },

            $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {                       //[Optional] Options to specify and enable thumbnail navigator or not
                $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,              //[Required] Class to create thumbnail navigator instance
                $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always

                $SpacingX: 8,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each thumbnail in pixel, default value is 0
                $Cols: 10,                             //[Optional] Number of pieces to display, default value is 1
                $Align: 360                          //[Optional] The offset position to park thumbnail
            }
        });
```

***Add caption element to slide***

```
<DIV>
    <IMG src="Beemer1.jpg" u="image">
    <div u="caption" t="L" style="position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 20px; width: 200px; height: 30px; color: #ffffff; font-size: 20px; line-height: 30px;">Caption Example</div>
    <IMG src="BeemerTN.jpg" u="thumb">
</DIV>
```